# imagejpeg(): Unable to open

Tags: php

PHP Warning:  imagejpeg(): Unable to open '.Project/events/timepass.jpg' for writing: No such file or directory in ./Project/upload/thumbnal.php on line 35

code..

```
<?php
    // open the directory

    $pathToImages="./Project/upload/original/";
    $dir = opendir($pathToImages);

    // loop through it, looking for any/all JPG files:
    while (false !== ($fname = readdir( $dir ))) 
    {
        // parse path for the extension
        $info = pathinfo($pathToImages . $fname);

        // continue only if this is a JPEG image
        if ( strtolower($info['extension']) == 'jpg') 
        {
            // echo "Creating thumbnail for {$fname} <br />";
            // load image and get image size
            $image_size=getimagesize( "{$pathToImages}{$fname}");

            $image_width=$image_size[0];
            $image_height=$image_size[1];

            $new_size=($image_width+$image_height)/($image_width*($image_height/80));
            $new_width=$image_width*$new_size;
            $new_height=$image_height*$new_size;

            $new_image=imagecreatetruecolor($new_width,$new_height);
            $old_image=imagecreatefromjpeg("{$pathToImages}{$fname}"); 

            imagecopyresized($new_image,$old_image,0,0,0,0,$new_width,$new_height,$image_width,$image_height);
            $pathToThumbs="./Project/events/$fname";
            imagejpeg($new_image,$pathToThumbs);
            // save thumbnail into a file
        }
    }
    // close the directory
    closedir( $dir );
?>
```

I am getting this error when i transferred my data from localhost to live server FTP.I searched on google some have recommanded for changing attributes of directory to 777.i did tat bt no use same warning.Please tell where should i make changes to make these code work.

Comment: That warning (about `../events/...`) doesn't fit to the image paths you have in the code snippet (`../upload/original/...`).

Comment: actually original are images i have uploaded on FTP iam opening tat directory making thumbnail of those images and transferring it to another directory i.e events

Comment: What I wanted to says: Are you sure, that the code you posted gives this Warning? There is no path containing something with `events`. Where is line 35? etc.

Comment: ya..! while copying 1st i made a mistake i was playing with paths n forgot to change :)

Answer (score 0):

You transfer the new image to a remote server?

Where is the path to the server? `Like "--IP TO SERVER--/Project/events/"`

The problem is, the path you have wrote can not be found on your local machine.

**UPDATE**

To upload the image to the FTP server have a look at this example:

```
<?php

$file = 'somefile.txt';
$ftp_server = "ftp.example.com";

// Connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// Login with user and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

// File upload
// $remote_file is the filename on the server 
// $file the filename on your local machine
if (ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $file, FTP_ASCII)) {
 echo "success\n";
} else {
 echo "error\n";
}

// Close connection
ftp_close($conn_id);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In general when you have such problems, make sure that the path exists and the user with which you try to upload the image has the necessary privileges to that path.